# Craft CMS admin pages return ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE locally

Tags: craft3, admin

Craft CMS admin pages don't load. Sometimes some pages like starting admin page or settings load, or load after refresh.
Chrome browser shows ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error.

Here is [video](https://monosnap.com/file/cAuLKqYkgBNeBHjbdSVzvEAoTMK2qz).

PHP version     7.4.29
OS version  Darwin 21.4.0
Database driver & version   MySQL 8.0.29
Image driver & version  GD 7.4.29
Craft edition & version     Craft Solo 3.7.39
Yii version     2.0.45
Twig version    v2.14.13
Guzzle version  7.4.2

Comment: How are you running the web server? I noticed in your screen cap that "not secure" is shown in Chrome on the front end but when you view the backend it goes away. Is SSL actually configured for that test site?

Comment: @RitterKnight I run it locally with apache. No SSL is configured locally.

Comment: @RitterKnight Looks like the page is initially xospa.test. And then turns into https://xospa.test/admin/dashboard. I do not know how to prevent adding `https` locally.

Comment: @RitterKnight I mean turns into `https://xospa.test/admin/dashboard`.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely receiving this error due to a problem with your Apache configuration.

A likely scenario is you're missing the `.htaccess` file or it could have an error. You should check your Apache logs and troubleshoot any errors you find.

This [knowledge base](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/removing-index-php-from-urls) article may also prove helpful in ensuring your Apache configuration and config is setup to correctly run Craft.

Comment: Nope, `web/.htaccess` is on its place and matches the recommendations.